# Figure out the ? in the figure below

Tags: physics

[image]

[Here is the link to the puzzle](https://alokgoyal1971.com/2016/12/11/puzzle-163-the-hatke-puzzle/)

Comment: Does v means frequency here?

Comment: That is the part of the puzzle ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is

> Energy
>
>  The diagram and numbers refer to the Sun's fusion reaction (our source of energy ) and talk about energy of the two photons emitted from the Sun in one fusion reaction
>  - $2$ refers to the mass of Deuterium so it represents **inertia** 
>  - $4$ refers the minimum number of Hydrogen atoms required for a fusion to take place also called **critical** mass 
>  - $f$ refers to frequency. Energy of a photon is directly proportional to it's frequency (Planck-Einstein relation), it the cause of **change** in energy  
>  - $h$ refers to the Planck constant. The reduced Planck constant is the quantum of angular momentum of a Photon 
>  - $8v$ refers to $(8 \times \tt{frequency})$. Energy of one photon is $hf$ by Planck-Einstein relation. Energy of the two photons will be $2hf$. Value of $h$ is $4.13 \times 10^{-15} \tt{\ eV}$. Since frequency of an emitted photon can vary, total energy emitted in one fusion reaction is approximately $2\times4\times f \times 4.13 \times 10^{-15}\tt{\ eV}$, which can also be written as ~$8f$ or $8v$ in the scientific notation.